# VBA Copy Row - > Paste Row with Column +1

Tags: excel, vba

I am just trying to Copy and Paste one row by

```
sht.Rows(rowCount).Copy Workbooks("TEST.xlsm").Sheets("TEXT").Rows("8")
```

when sht is my selected sheet from another file (don´t worry about it, it works),
but I need to paste it with offset 1 column (from A to B). Any elegant and easy idea?

Comment: `.Cells(8,2)` ? Or what do you mean

Comment: You need to paste the copy... look in the help for Paste Special

Comment: I pasting copy to selected destination after space